# How to run multi browser tests sequentially in Protractor?

Tags: javascript, protractor

For e.g., I have 5 TCs and need to run all the 5 test cases on both Firefox and Chrome. So, once the Chrome finished executing 5 TCs, I need the Firefox browser to initiate and do that same job sequentially.

When I use multiCapabilities, it launches both the Firefox and Chrome at a time.

Comment: can you give little more insight on why exactly you want to be run sequentially? It can be done in rather tedious way which will involve browser.forkNewDriverInstance(). See if this method helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `maxSessions`var inside protractor configuration `conf.js`

```
  // Maximum number of total browser sessions to run. Tests are queued in
  // sequence if number of browser sessions is limited by this parameter.
  // Use a number less than 1 to denote unlimited. Default is unlimited.
  maxSessions: -1
```

More info https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js#L198

Example `conf.js` (firefox, safari, chrome, chrome device simulators):

```
multiCapabilities: [
    {
        browserName: 'firefox'
    },
     {
     browserName: 'safari'
     },
    {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    },
    {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        // List of devices https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/test/chromedriver/chrome/mobile_device_list.cc
        'deviceName': 'Google Nexus 5'
    },
    {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        'deviceName': 'Apple iPhone 6'
    },
    {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        'deviceName': 'Apple iPad'
    },
    {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        'deviceName': 'Samsung Galaxy S4'
    }
],
maxSessions: 1
```

More examples and testing in real devices https://github.com/aluzardo/protractor-cucumber-tests

Comment: Thank you Adolfo  it helped me a lot . I was able to achieve my requirement as my answer in below .

Answer (score 1):

This has been tested and working  fine in protractor Version 5.4.2 and as per **Adolfo's** answer I added maxSessions: 1, so it runs in sequential mode . In other words, firefox specs get executed first and then chrome .

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  directConnect: false,


  multiCapabilities: [{
      browserName: 'firefox',
      'moz:firefoxOptions': {
            args: ['--verbose'],
            binary: 'C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe'
       //Need to start cmd via admin mode to avoid permission error
        },
      specs: ['src/com/sam/scriptjs/draganddrop.spec.js']
    }, 
    {
        browserName : 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: [ "--start-maximized" ]
                     },
        specs: ['src/com/sam/scriptjs/iframes.spec.js']

    }],
    maxSessions: 1,//To run in sequential mode so first Firefox then chrome 
    //without max session it will open two windows at the same time for both browsers
     seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'

}
```